# Aptana Warns about script and link tags when it shouldn't

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.1.3.201205292243, Win7 64bit, and I've noticed that after the last update, Aptana is warning me (annotations on the vertical) that I should "trim empty " tags, but these are normal script tags linking an external js file like this:

```
    <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flickrapi3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flickrStyle.css" />
```

Furthermore, it also warns me about the rel attribute inside the link tag as having an "invalid value" and yet these are the defaults included in the HTML5 template Aptana bundles with the release.

I've checked in Preferences>Editors>Text Editors and I see annotation settings but I don't see where I can correct these completely off the wall warnings.  Am I missing something entirely here?  Are these known bugs?  How do I correct these issue?

Comment: Yeah it does that with me too. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a trick, and make the `</script>` in a new line, the warning will disappear, like this below:

```
<script src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js">
</script>
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! Is this issue related to formatting in the editor preferences?  In other words, could I adjust my preferences so that perhaps it will accept the script tag all on one line?

Comment: also, any idea regarding the warning on the rel attribute for the link tags?

Comment: @max7 Also, I found that if you just put a space between the text and the end tag it will remove the error also. Like this: 

`<script src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"> </script>`

Comment: didn't see Russdog's answer. Oops! :)

Answer (score 18):

Go to Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML.

Change the two checks by "HTML Tidy Validator" into "X".  Alternatively, you could click "+" to add a regular expression to filter out the error.

Comment: I would have selected this answer as the correct one, as it involves a proper solution, and not a workaround to avoid the warning.

Comment: Nice answer,should be selected.

Answer (score 6):

Another even simpler workaround to hide the warning is to just put a space in between the tags.

```
<script src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"> </script>
```

Comment: This is also an excellent solution!  I'm new to stackoverflow; is there a way to give credit to multiple user for their answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you find it annoying having the warning for more than just script tags you can disable it all tags

Go to Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation

Select `HTML Tidy Validator` then some collapse-able options will appear. Select `Elements`, it will show a list of option. Now go to the bottom of the list and you'll see `Trim empty elements` Change it from `warning` to `ignore`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in version 3.2.0.201206061952:  https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4724
So you can pull a nightly build or just wait for them to promote it to release.