# Trim empty HTML tag

Tags: html, aptana

I have in my HTML code this line:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```

As editor I use Aptana.

How can I solve this warning? What does it mean?

> "Should trim empty `<iframe>`."

[image: "Should trim empty <iframe>."]

Comment: I see no reason for this warning. Upvoting.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864546/aptana-warns-about-script-and-link-tags-when-it-shouldnt

Comment: @nlsbshtr is iFrame allowed to be self-closing?

Comment: @nisbshtr: No, for `<iframe .... /> it says: "Should trim empty <iframe>" and "self-closing syntax (/>) - used a non-void HTML element.".

Comment: Aptana has all kinds of warnings for stuff that isn't actually wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because there is no body for the `iframe` tag.

One option to remove the warning will be putting the closing tag in a different line:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com">
</iframe>
```

Or adding a space:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com"> </iframe>
```

Comment: @John You should check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864546/aptana-warns-about-script-and-link-tags-when-it-shouldnt

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the reasons for the warning might be, there is a reason to include content in an `iframe` element: it is meant to be the *fallback* content, for use if (and only if) display of inline frames is not supported by the browser or the support has been disabled. Therefore, you could provide e.g. a link as fallback content:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com"><a href="http://example.com">
Some useful title for the page</a></iframe>
```

This is of limited usefulness, but at least Opera still has a user-settable option for disabling inline frames. And since inline frames have been said to be a security concern of a kind, some people may wish to disable them. Besides, a content like a link surely silences the warning.

**Correction** (Oct 4, 2013): HTML5 requires the `iframe` content to be just text, and Opera (when configured to not support inline frames) plays by that book: it shows the content as is, without intepreting anything as tags. For completeness, I need to add that the good old Lynx browser treats `iframe` content so that markup is interpreted – but it also automatically shows a link to the resource specified by the `src` attribute. So for practical purposes, the content of `iframe` is rather pointless.